# Git how to view first 8 commits of a repo in one line?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-log

I am using windows powershell and I want to view the first 8 commits of a repo in a single line.

```
git log --reverse --oneline
```

Displays what I want, but too many of them. I only want 8 commits.

```
git log --reverse --oneline -8
```

Displays 8 in one line, but the last 8 commits whereas I want the first 8 commits.

How can I display the first 8 commits in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git log --reverse --oneline --pretty=format:'%h %aI | %s%d [%an]' | head -8
```

where `--pretty=format:'%h %aI | %s%d [%an]'` is totally optional, but I like to have it. :)

Also you can of course change `8` to whatever number of commits you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end

> git log --reverse --oneline | Select-Object -First 8

Here's the pretty format using styling suggested by syohey

> git log --reverse --oneline --pretty=format:'%h %aI | %s%d [%an]' | Select-Object -First 8

`head -8` was not recognized, I guess powershell doesn't support it. Later, I discovered `Select-Object -First 8` was the powershell counterpart, or at least a working solution for what I wanted.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I should've mentioned what system I use... Glad you found a solution though!